# IE 11 preventing popup from opening due to quotations in url

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working with a ASP.Net App but having an issue with a popup window whose url contains quotation marks.

In the code the url is something like `http://www.example.com?a=7&b='misc'&c=23`

The code uses escape clauses to generate the url so that the string parameter looks like: `"http://www.example.com?a=7&b=//'misc//'&c=23"`

The problem is that when this popup is triggered on our dev and QA web servers IE11 just displays a # and the message

> "Internet Explorer has modified this page to prevent Cross Site
>   Scripting".

This does not occur when I run the code locally. In this case the popup opens up as expected.

If I type the popup url directly into the browser ie `(http://www.example.com?a=7&b='misc'&c=23)`
it opens locally but not on the two servers.

Why will it open locally but not on the Web Servers and how can I resolve this issue so that it runs on all of them?

Comment: Can you show us the code for opening the url? It sounds like you might be escaping the string improperly, but I can't say fore sure.

Comment: You don't escape a single quote with a double slash. You should instead encode it, `'` becomes `%27`. Likely whatever is generating the URL has an encoder you can take advantage of.